# CMake reports broken g++ and missing libiconv-2.dll

Tags: windows, gcc, cmake, cmake-gui

I have some strange problem with CMake when I press `Configure` button.

It reports me all the time that `libiconv-2.dll` is missing and fails to finish operation. However, this library is present in MinGW/bin folder.

I am using CodeBlocks-MinGW Makefiles and CMake version 3.6.1 - 32 bit version (although this same problem is with 64 bit version).
One interesting thing is that in consol it shows:

> The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>
> Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
>
> Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- broken

MinGW is correctly added to the system path and I was able to check version (GNU 4.8.1) and also compile simple hello world from command line using:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

Testing this same CMakeLists file on another machine with this same configuration, but older CMake version 3.2.3 everything works. Doing some research online I've found that problem with this file is not new, so I doubt this is version problem.

Anyone has any idea what can be done more?

**EDIT 1**
This is the content of CMakeError.log

> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed. Compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  Build
>   flags:  Id flags: -c
>
> The output was: 1
>
> Checking whether the CXX compiler is IAR using "" did not match "IAR
>   .+ Compiler": g++.exe: fatal error: no input files compilation
>   terminated. Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the
>   following output: Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_c9a03/fast"
>   C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9a03.dir\build.make
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_c9a03.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://sscce.org/): Entering directory
>   'C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c9a03.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
>
> C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe      -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9a03.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c
>   C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_c9a03.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_c9a03.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://sscce.org/): ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c9a03.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1](http://sscce.org/): Leaving directory
>   'C:/Users/testuser/Desktop/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_c9a03/fast' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_c9a03/fast] Error 2

I have manually compiled the file `testCXXCompiler.cpp` with g++ and it worked. There was no error during compilation.

**EDIT 2**

I have created [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to test if problem isn't with some dependencies or some other code-related things. But testing this file:

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(Test)
add_executable(Test test.cpp)
```

I have still problems with missing library. The console output changed however slightly and now it is:

> The C compiler identification is unknown
>
> The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>
> Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
>
> Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken

Comment: Looks like a broken installation of MinGW.

Comment: @usr1234567 I doubt that, because I can compile with MinGW in every other case - from command line, from Code::Blocks

Comment: Can you compile the test program CMake gives in the CMakeError.out file with the same command as given there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I have found the answer. At least it is working for me.

Apparently I needed to run the CMake on the other machine as an **Administrator**. This way I assume it could accessed to GCC files correctly. However, I am not completely sure why on the other machine it wasn't required and worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to reinstall the lib

```
mingw-get install --reinstall mingw32-libiconv-dll
```

I had a very similar problem, and it was fixed this way.